# I wonder if the sentence after the comma is complete or not and am having a problem of translating it

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> Hume was tireless, his ponderous public style betraying a quicksilver ability to analyse the issues.

I found this sentence on some website. I'm afraid there are more contexts other than this sentence.
I'm having a problem of translating the sentence after comma:

> his ponderous public style betraying a quicksilver ability to analyse the issues.

is that sentence regarded as a complete sentence? if so, what sentence structure is this called? it seems like "betraying" is serving as verb but why is it in the form of present participle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply another way to say "Hume was tireless and his public style betrayed a quicksilver ability..."
Remember, present participles do not determine the tense. You may find [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316388/can-present-participle-verbs-be-used-in-past-tense-stories) useful.

It's rather old-fashioned writing, pheno8. And I don't think it's quite correct.

Lexico's (second) definition of [betray](https://www.lexico.com/definition/betray) is: Unintentionally reveal; be evidence of.

So in *your* example Hume's slow speech unintentionally reveals his quick mind. How can that be? Usually someone who speaks slowly *thinks* slowly! Perhaps it should be:
*his ponderous public style **concealing** a quicksilver ability to analyse the issues.*

'Betray' is more commonly used like this:

**Although he claimed to be Irish, his accent betrayed a childhood spent in Birmingham.**
('He *said* he was Irish but he had a Birmingham accent.' Or we might say, '...but his Birmingham accent betrayed him'.)

An equally old-fashioned word - [bespeak](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bespeak) - has a similar meaning, but without implying something has been revealed unintentionally:

**He was English, and his accent bespoke a childhood spent in Birmingham.**
*He was English and had a Birmingham accent.*

Comment: thanks for the answer. the link you've added is really helpful! so in this case, as far as I understand, the sentence is an old-fashioned writing way of "Hume was tireless and his public style betrayed a quicksilver ability...", but if the speaker says it in a sarcastic way, does it still sound weird?

Comment: @pheno8: It's a serious article from The Guardian. The writer is NOT being sarcastic.

Comment: Yes, but I just want to make it clear. I mean, not just about it's from a serious article but if I imagine that sentence is uttered in a casual conversation although they might not use the word "betray" for what they intend to say in such situation, will it still be not correct?